# Изменение размера таблицы при удалении колонок в postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Почему когда я удаляю колонку из таблицы в postres, размер её (таблицы, 20 млн строк) не уменьшается??? Колонка varchar, удаляю обычной командой 
alter table ... drop column

Можно как-то исправить эту ситуацию??

Как смотрю размер:

> select pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size( 'items_fin' ) )

Как удаляю:

> alter table items_fin drop column user_id

Базу обновляю, конечно, после удаления колонки.

(Прим.: когда создаю новую колонку и задаю значения для новой колонки - конечно, размер увеличивается.)

Comment: `vacuum FULL ANALYZE tablename`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: Удаление поля из структуры меняет только структуру. Наличие в области данных неиспользуемых блоков, хранивших данные удалённого поля, в общем не сильно мешает. Приоритет БД - всё-таки скорость, пусть и ценой дискового пространства. Соответственно быстренько изменяем структуру, а данные пожмём потом, когда на это будет время. А вот при добавлении поля от добавления новых блоков в области данных никуда не деться -
 иначе данные нового поля некуда будет засунуть.

Comment: а сколько вы всякого хлама храните - типа вдруг пригодится? )) 
на самом деле задача СУБД - как можно быстрее выполнить запрос, оптимизация занимаемого места при каждом запросе - слишком сложная, дорогая и оперативно ненужная операция - админы это могут делать во время простоя или минимальной нагрузки БД

Comment: @norbornen super !!! сработтало. уменьшися размер в 3 раза.

Comment: @Viktorov Супер, спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 4):

Удаление поля из определения таблицы не затрагивает саму таблицу. Вообще не затрагивает, лишь в системном каталоге [pg_attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html) проставляется свойство `attisdropped`.

Это хорошо и плохо одновременно. Хорошо потому что операция быстрая и не зависит от объёма данных. Плохо - потому что уменьшить размер таблицы за счёт удаления удалённых данных бывает нетривиально.

Для небольших таблиц или если есть возможность заблокировать таблицу на заметное время - поможет [`vacuum full`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) - внимание, именно `full`. Просто вакуум, как и автовакуум не будут вычищать данные из неизменившихся и видимых версий строк.

Для таблиц сильно побольше, которые блокировать нельзя - можно использовать [pg_repack](http://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/). Необходимо только учитывать, что `repack` не имеет никаких настроек производительности и в работе даст ощутимую нагрузку на диски и на реплики (если таковые есть).

Третий вариант без длительной блокировки - небольшими транзакциями вида

```
update testtable set any_column = any_column where ...;
```

обновить все записи в таблице, делая время от времени `vacuum tablename` (не `full`). Во время `update` содержимое удалённых колонок не копируется. В конце может иметь смысл запустить [`pgcompacttable`](https://github.com/dataegret/pgcompacttable) для проверки таблицы и индексов на раздутость и автоматическое сжатие без длинных блокировок. Опций по удалению удалённых колонок у этой утилиты нет, но зато она спроектирована оказывать минимальное влияние на производительность базы.